# AFNetwork 2.0 POST results in a 403 error

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2, restler

I'm using AFNetworking 2 to perform a simple post operation:

```
    [self.manager POST:@"person"
        parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
constructingBodyWithBlock:nil
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
               if (success)
                   success(responseObject);
           } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
               if (failure)
                   failure(error);
           }];
```

Every time this runs, XCode's console says that I got "Request failed: forbidden (403)" as the response.  If I run against the exact same url shown in the NSErrorFailingURLKey via curl, I immediately get back the results I'd expect from the POST operation.

I haven't enabled any type of authentication on the script being called.  It's just a Restler class.  Am I missing a step here?

Comment: curl like so works:  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"email":"foo@bar.com",....}' http://..../person

Answer (score 0):

Adding the 'constructingBodyWithBlock' changed the type of message being sent.  Had to remove that in order to make it work.